# recursively dissect sql schema

Tags: sql, postgresql, tkinter, schema, dbeaver

I use DBeaver with postgresql. It has a feature that lists a tree view of a db's schemas, including information_schema, pg_catalog, and public. Then, within each schema, there are a set of headings: Tables, Views, Materialized Views, Indexes, Functions, Sequences, Data Types, Aggregate Functions. Within each of these headings there are other entities, and so on to several levels in depth.

I would like to create that tree view independently of DBeaver, using tkinter. I can handle the tkinter part, but I haven't been able to divine the SQL statements that dissect schemas recursively down to leaf nodes. I've only found the topmost statement, which is:

```
select schema_name from information_schema.schemata
```

Beyond that, I cannot find anything that enables me to display deeper structure. I have read all the so-called schema tutorials; they are focused only on user-created tables. I've also read the official postgresql docs on schemas; they read like a dictionary and have no tutorial value whatever.

Any help, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You find all required information (e. g. `schemata`, `tables`, `views`, `sequences`, etc.) in the `information_schema` schema, which you can inspect with DBeaver. The PostgreSQL information schema is documented at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/information-schema.html . Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. I've since discovered the psql -e flag, which gives the sql for each psql command. Also, I've determined that the list of items I gave in the OP do not reflect the hierarchical ordering found in the schemata; instead, they are a convenience created by the DBeaver author.